# till the end of the string - Regex

Tags: php, regex, replace

I'm parsing an external feed which contains location and date inside post title which I want to get rid of, so:

`This happened on Date in Location`

I need to find `on` (space on space) and remove everything till the end of the line, same for `in`(space in space).

I googled a bit, but regex is really unfathomable for me so I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a literal "`on`" does match exactly. Then tell the regex engine to match everything after: "`.*`". (Note, that the `.` doesn't match newlines, so it works as needed.)

In the case of "`in`" you need an alternative, which is marked by parentheses `()` and the vertical bar `|`: "`(on|in)`". You could also make that a bit tighter with character classes `[]`: "`[oi]n`".

With that we arrive at this regex:

```
/ [oi]n .*/
```

Answer (score 0):

To the end of the line? Then I suppose:

```
preg_replace("/(?:on|in).*?(\n|$)/", "", 'This happened on Date in Location');
```

Would do it.

Comment: That returns "This happened on". Doesn't look like what I've got from the question.

Comment: I wasn't sure whenever he wanted the 'on' be saved or not. I suppose not then, so changed to "This happened " instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookbehind if you want to remove everything after the `on` and `in` but not the `on` and `in` themselves.

```
(?<=\son\s).*
```

and

```
(?<=\sin\s).*
```

http://regexr.com?30ops